# What is the state,the during vipassana meditation?

Tags: meditation, vipassana, enlightenment

Now there is no bodily sensation on sitting posture of meditation. Only thoughts are coming. Always  close  the eyes can see a oil lamp in the Middle. When  the lamp not appeared in the front negative thoughts were coming. When experience breath slowly  body disappears. Sometimes thinking loose and mindfulness  appears. Can anyone tell is it sankaraupeksha ?

Comment: How long have you been meditating for? Sankharupekkha nana is characterized by equanimity and consistency of and strength of concentration, similarly to the fourth samatha jhana, does that seem to accurately describe where you are?

Comment: I have been meditating for10 years 20 minutes per day.thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is the state called "Passambayan Kayasankharam" or "Sabbakaya Patisamvedhi" state.

[3] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in sensitive to the entire body.'[2] He trains himself, 'I will breathe out sensitive to the entire body.' [4] He trains himself, 'I will breathe in calming bodily fabrication.'[3] He trains himself, 'I will breathe out calming bodily fabrication.'

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html